# Batch rename *fastq.gz files using regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, perl, rename, fastq

I'm trying to get a regex to work with `rename`; I've tried the approach of similar answered questions here but couldn't get the results I wanted.

The files are named as such:

```
SR1_S90_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 
SR1_S90_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Rinc_S96_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 
Rinc_S96_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

And I would like to retain *only* the information prior to the first underscore and the _R1_ or _R2_ tags, like this:

```
SR1_R1_.fastq.gz 
SR1_R2_.fastq.gz
Rinc_R1_.fastq.gz 
Rinc_R2_.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Just to further complement the answers bellow, [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/323148/) are other approaches

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @jww I had no intention to indolently ask this (and any other questions, for that matter). I researched (this forum and other resources) and tried several approaches. We all have limitations and mine (in this case) come from a background and biology and not computer sciences (hence my previous comment, indicating further answers on the Biostars forum). I'm very thankful for the `stackoverflow community` for all the support (mostly indirect) over the past years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename 's{^([^._]+)_[^.]*(_R[12]_)[^.]*}{$1$2}' *
```

The idea is to match (and capture) the first part of the string (1 or more characters that are not `.` or `_`), followed by `_` and 0 or more non-`.` characters, followed by `_R1_` or `_R2_` (we capture this part, too), followed by 0 or more non-`.` characters yet again.

This should match the first part of the filename (before `.`) and replace it by the first and second captured substrings, i.e. everything before the first `_` and the R1/R2 tag.

Comment: `rename` is not a program, but a built-in perl funciton. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html

Comment: @blhsing http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of such a command. Given the lack of code I think the OP is indeed referring to the command, not the built-in perl function then.

Comment: @melpomene is right, I meant the perl implementation of the command `rename`, as pointed out in the reference above

Comment: Works flawlessly! Just add the -n option to just print the output.

Running:
`rename -n 's{^([^._]+)_[^.]*(_R[12]_)[^.]*}{$1$2}' *.fastq,gz`

Outputs:
`rename(Rinc_S96_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, Rinc_R1_.fastq.gz)
rename(Rinc_S96_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz, Rinc_R2_.fastq.gz)
rename(SR1_S90_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, SR1_R1_.fastq.gz)
rename(SR1_S90_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz, SR1_R2_.fastq.gz)`

Thanks @melpomene!

Answer (score 0):

The following does the renaming you want in the current directory:

```
opendir DIR, '.';
for (readdir DIR) {
  /^([^_]+).*(_(?:R1|R2)_)[^_]+(\.fastq\.gz)$/ or next;
  rename $_, "$1$2$3";
}
```

Comment: `Can't "continue" outside a when block at - line 3.` Also, I assume OP is trying to use the `rename` program.

Comment: I meant to type `next`, not `continue`. The answer has been corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @blhsing! The script works :) Just a few clarifications for future references: this is a perl scrip, to run it call `perl script_name`

Comment: @LeonardoNormando No problem. Glad to be of help. A +1 vote would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers.. And, at the moment, I don't have enough reputation to vote :( I will get back to you later, don't worry